# How to disable send and show messages in input for complete

Tags: jquery, forms

How do I display in-form messages and disable form submission with jQuery?

I would like to show in-form messages with jQuery on text input fields that are required to submit and disable the submit button before the fields are filled out.

My simple questions is this:

I want to display error messages if input fields are empty and disable the submit button.  If input fields are empty I want to display messages near the input field that is empty and needs to be filled out.

I tried

```
$("#CustomerForm").validate({
  rules: {
    FirstNameEdit: { required: true },
    LastNameEdit: { required: true },
    EmailEdit: { required: true, email:true }
  }
});
```

But it doesn't work.

Head

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.fx.speeds._default = 650;
$(function() {
  $('.massgejava').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: 'explode',
    hide: 'explode',
    title: 'راسلنا',
    width: 380
  });
  $('#javamassge').click(function() {
    $(".massgejava").dialog('open');
    return false;
  });
  $('input#registerjquery').click(function() {
    $(".massgejava").dialog("close");
  });
});
</script>
```

Body

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
  <input name="name" 
         type="text" 
         value="اسمك الكريم" 
         onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'اسمك الكريم'" 
         onclick="value=''" />
  <input name="email" 
         type="text" 
         value="البريد الالكتروني" />
  <input name="phone" 
         type="text" 
         value="رقم الهاتف" 
         onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'رقم الهاتف'" 
         onclick="value=''" />
  <textarea name="msg" 
            cols="41" 
            rows="5" 
            placeholder = "نص الرساله" 
            wrap="soft"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="ارسال" />
</form>
```

Suggestions?

Comment: probably no one understood your question. it is the case for me at least.

Comment: my questions is

i want display error messages if input empty and stop submit button from work if input empty and display messages in input is this falid empty and need to fil input

Comment: He wants to display error messages in the form if the `<input>` fields are empty, and prevent the submit button from working if the input is empty, and display error messages which say if the inputs are invalid.

Comment: thx calvinf yes this i want do

Answer (score 1):

Form with some added IDs:

```
<form action="form.php" method="post" id="CustomerForm">
    <input name="name" type="text" value="اسمك الكريم" onblur="if (this.value=='')this.value='اسمك الكريم'" onclick="value=''" />
    <br />
    <input name="email" type="text" value="البريد الالكتروني" />
    <br />
    <input name="phone" type="text" value="رقم الهاتف" onblur="if (this.value=='')this.value='رقم الهاتف'" onclick="value=''" />
    <br />
    <textarea name="msg" id="msg" cols="41" rows="5" placeholder="نص الرساله" wrap=soft></textarea>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="ارسال" />
</form>
```

JQuery:

```
function kontrolaMailu(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
}

function checkName(name){
var pattern = new RegExp(/^([a-z]+) ([a-z]+)$/);
return pattern.test(name);
}

function formControl(){
var error=0;
var errorTXT='';
var inputs = $("#CustomerForm input ");
$.each(inputs, function(key, value) {
    if(value["name"]=='name'){
        if(value['value']!='' && error==0){
            if(checkName(value['value'])){
                error=0;
                }
                else{
                    error=1;
                    errorTXT='your error msg text for name input when there arent two words';
                    return false;
                }
        }
        else{
            error=1;
            errorTXT='your error msg text for empty name field';
            return false;
            }
        }
     if(value["name"]=='email'){
        if(value['value']!='' && error==0){
            if(kontrolaMailu(value['value'])){
                error=0;
                }
                else{
                    error=1;
                    errorTXT='your error msg text for wrong mail format';
                    return false;
                }

        }
        else{
            error=1;
            errorTXT='your error msg text for empty mail';
            return false;
            }
        }
}

     if(error != 0){
      $('#submit').attr('title',errorTXT);
      $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('#submit').addClass('disabled');//css class for disabled button
      $('#msg').val(errorTXT);
     }
     else{
      $('#submit').removeAttr('title');
      $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('#submit').removeClass('disabled');//css class for disabled button
      $('#msg').val('');
     }
}
```

I am not shure if values like value='اسمك الكريم'  will pass those RegExps cuz I never had to work whith languge using diferent charset